# Issue with applying partially-applied functions in-line

Tags: scala

Being relatively new at Scala, I was playing around with partially-applied function syntax on sbt console.  I ran into a very weird issue in which I do not understand Scala's behavior.

The example is contrived and would unlikely be encountered in reality.  That said, here it is.  Suppose I define the following function:

```
scala> def f(x: Int, y: Int) = "%d %d".format(x, y)
```

Now if I type in

```
scala> f(1, _:Int)(2)
res: Int => Char = <function1>
```

The result is a `Int => Char` function, which is very unusual.  In other words, Scala is (temporarily) treating `f(1, _:Int)` as a String (vs. its actual type: `Int => String`) when applying the parameter (i.e., 2).

If, instead, parentheses are used, what I expect to happen occurs:

```
scala> (f(1, _:Int))(2)
res: String = 1 2
```

However, this does not appear to be an order-of-operations issue, as I cannot find a way to add parentheses to achieve the unexpected behavior (i.e., having the result be of type `Int => Char`).

Any ideas?

Comment: This is surprising to me, and seems at odds with my reading of section 6.23 of the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), which says that an underscore is bound by the smallest expression that contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first about the result type of:

```
scala> f(1, _:Int)(2)
res: Int => Char = <function1>
```

Check this out:

```
scala> val str = "hello"
str: String = hello

scala> str(2)
res12: Char = l
```

I think this is clear.

No to the function itself, as it also easy. When you are lifting it to a function with an underscore you are lifting not only `f`, but also with a call `(2)` on a string (first result), which is why you get:

```
res: Int => Char = <function1>
```

**Added**

More explicit version. You function `f` is of type `(Int, Int) => String`, when you write `f(1, _: Int)`, you are partially applying it to the argument one and returning a function of type `Int => String`, where `Int` is the second argument. Then your argument `(2)` call `apply` method on the result string from the function `Int => String` which returns you a `Char`, from here you get function of type `Int => Char`, where `Int` is a second argument to your `f` function and `Char` is a char from the resulting string

In the second case, where you have:

```
scala> (f(1, _:Int))(2)
res: String = 1 2
```

by parenthesis you are spliting this into to things, the first one is a function `Int => String` and `(2)` calls this function, you are passing an argument `2` into this function `Int => String`:

```
val ff = f(1, _: Int)
val res = ff(2)
```

Comment: So I understand why, if `f(1, _:Int)` were a String, `f(1, _:Int)(2)` would be a `Char`.  However, what I don't understand is why `f(1, _:Int)` is being treated as a String to begin with, when its type is `Int => Char`.

Comment: @bacchuswng You wrote it yourself: `def f(x: Int, y: Int) = "%d %d".format(x, y)` f takes two ints and returns a string

Comment: @bacchuswng i've updated the answer to be more clearer in this moment

Comment: It still seems counterintuitive to me why, when calling `apply(2)` on the result of `f(1, _: Int)`, Scala treats this as an `apply(2)` on the `String` result of applying `f(1, _: Int)` vs. the `Int => String` result of `f(1, _: Int)` itself.  Perhaps I just need to accept this as how Scala is :).

Comment: @bacchuswng cause we can think of `f(1, _:Int).apply` in term of curried function of type `Int => String => Char`, that's how currying works. If you wrap it in brackets (f(1, _:Int))(2) this is not a curried function, first you get `Int => String` and then pass `2` as an argument